Probabilities I'm gonna win a tournament when I'm better at one game and bad at another
I'm playing a game of chess and go. It's a three round game and to win I have to win two rounds in a row. I'm better at chess and my opponent is better at go. I can chose to play go-chess-go or chess-go-chess. Is there one that gives me better chances to win two in a row ? since winning the second round is crucial intuitively I would say go-chess-go gives me better chances but when I try to calculate I find that it's equal am I doing something wrong ?

Please share your computations

Let's say I have 65% chance to win in chess(C) and 40% to win in go(G). in the sequence C-G-C I can win with C-G or G-C so 0.650.4 + 0.40.65 = 52%. in the sequence G-C-G I can win with either G-C or C-G so 0.40.65 + 0.650.4 = 52%.

@whyu You made a natural error, and mis-computed.  You can't compute the abbreviated sequences of two games that way.  Instead, you have to compute each possible $~3~$ game sequence, and sum up the possibilities.  For example, in the sequence C-G-C, you have to compute the sequences W-W-W, W-W-L, L-W-W.  See also, the answer of infinitezero.

Let $c$ be the probability you win in chess and $g$ that you win in go, with $c>1/2>g$.
We can win the first two games and the third doesn't matter, or lose the first game and win the last two. This is where your mistake was. You overcounted the first round.
Go-Chess-go:
$$P_1 = g c + (1-g)cg = 2gc - c g^2$$
Chess-go-chess:
$$P_2=c g + (1-c)g c = 2gc - gc^2$$
From this, $P_1 > P_2$, so playing two rounds of go is the better option.

Why is the assumption $c > 1/2 > g$ instead of just $c > g$?

it's because my opponent is better than me at go c>g could mean I'm better than him in both but we know that g is less than 1/2
